# My oilpan fell off my 2007 mazda 6

Tags: engine, mazda, mazda-6, oil-pan

I just got this car and i noticed a ticking noise I checked the oil it was low so i put 3 quarts in still the noise persisted its only been less then a month that i got it but  yesterday i was going 20 to 30 miles I heard something underneath come from from my car, my car stopped when i got out i see half of the oilpan had came off and alot of oil was coming out. Its never overheated and no warning lights ever came on.If i put a new oil pan on will my car run or Is my car a done deal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: My biggest concern here is WHY the oil pan was loose to begin with.  While I suppose it might have just worked itself loose that seems highly unlikely.

More likely is that someone previously took it off and did not reinstall it properly.  But taking the oil pan off is not routine by any means.  I suspect they were concerned about a serious engine problem and once they confirmed that they half-arsed the pan back on and sold it.

Answer (score 0):

No one here can answer your question, as the time the engine was running without oil and the damage the engine may have suffered — if any — cannot be known without a physical examination of the engine. Such an exam may require some mechanical disassembly of the engine. You will need a capable and experienced mechanic to make this assessment.

There may be no damage at all, or the damage may be significant enough to require replacement of the engine. If the engine requires a complete rebuild or replacement, usually obtaining a used or remanufactured motor would be less expensive.

On the other hand, depending on repair or engine replacement costs, it may make more economic sense to scrap the car and obtain another vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

If the oil light didn't come on you're probably fine.

Are you saying that the 15-20 bolts on your oil pan all just spontaneously came off?  If find this extremely hard to imagine.  Do you have an evil nemesis who would do this to your car?  The other option is you hit something that tore the pan off.